# ArrayList - Colocar índice ao lado do elemento

Tags: java, array, lista, arraylist

Tenho uma aplicação em que o usuário informa via JSF um nome de unidade.

Quando o sistema encontra a unidade, ele preenche um `List<String>` com os dados da unidade. Com esse `List` preenchido, preciso colocar o índice de cada linha ao lado do respectivo elemento:

```
[0] - elemento da linha aqui
[1] - elemento da linha aqui 1
[2] - elemento da linha aqui 2
[3] - etc
```

Consigo imprimir no console, mas ao enviar para a JSF os dados são sobrepostos.

meu bean esta assim:

```
public List<String> getUnidadesAdicionadas() {
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

            if (!findUnidadeCampanha(unidade)) {
                addMensagemErro("erro");
            }  else { 
            unidadesAdd.add(unidade.getNome());
            quantidadeUnidades = unidadesAdd.size();


            lista.addAll(unidadesAdd);

            for (int i = 1; i < unidadesAdd.size(); i++) {   
                //Para cada item percorrido   atribuir o valor na variavel indice;
                String elemento  = unidadesAdd.get(i) + "\n";
                 int  index  = i++;
                }

            unidade.setNome("");//limpar campo UNIDADE


        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

e meu jsf assim:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{proformeGerencialMBean.index}"  escape="false" />   - <h:outputText value="#{proformeGerencialMBean.elemento}"  escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

De cara deu pra ver que você está retornando a mesma lista em vez de unidadesAdd que é a que você está mexendo com os index, não seria retornar unidadesAdd?

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Essa lista que você criou sempre nunca vai ter a alteração porque só está adicionando o elemento nela.

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar seu for para:

```
for (int i = 1; i < lista.size(); i++) {   
    //Para cada item percorrido   atribuir o valor na variavel indice;
    String elemento  = lista.get(i) + "\n";
    int  index  = i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução seria mais ou menos isso talvez tenha que criar outra lista e adicionar os elementos nela, tem que testar pra ver.

```
Integer contador = 0;

for (String elemento : lista) {   
    //Para cada item percorrido atribuir o valor na variavel indice;
    elemento = "[" + contador + "]" + elemento;
    contador++;
}
```